# Mac Developer Program & free copies of OS X

Tags: developer-program, macos

The Mac Developer program is advertised as including access to [Pre-Release Software](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/software.html) (which right now means betas of Mavericks). Once Mavericks is released, will everyone with a Mac Developer account get a free copy/upgrade to the released version (including all future Mavericks updates)? Or will it be necessary for developers to also purchase Mavericks itself to be able to use the normal version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Lion, the developer program issues its beta seeds of the OS using the Mac App Store.  You get a code in the developer portal which is redeemed in the Mac App Store. You can redeem this code on any Apple ID. It does NOT need to be the Apple ID that you  signed up with on the dev portal.  Once the final release is out, the beta seed in your App Store is transformed into the fully released version.

So yes, you do get it. And in fact, you will be unable to purchase it on the Apple ID with which you redeemed the seed.

Comment: This answer meshes well with other things I've since read that implied this was the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mavericks is free for every Mac user :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the developer previews have an expiry date on them (typically some modest period of time beyond the release of the next version/release version). In addition, to upgrade to point versions (*i.e.* 10.9.1, etc.), you need to be running the release version.

So while you could run the final release candidate for some time, for any sort of long term use, you'll want to buy it fully.

Comment: The direct answer is no. Those that hold developer accounts do not receive a final, retail copy of OS X.

Comment: Actually, you do.